# Push from github to heroku without downloading repo

Tags: git, github, heroku

I have a github repo that I want to push to a heroku node. A 3rd host will be co-ordinating this. As I'm going to be doing this on a large scale I want to avoid having to download the contents of the repo onto the 3rd host. How do I do it?

Comment: This is now supported by Heroku - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't push straight from Github to Heroku.

You're going to have to use the third host to coordinate the push. This could be fired from a Github post-receive hook.

To sync straight across use something like:

```
git remote add github git@github.com:user/repo.git
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:app.git

git push heroku refs/remotes/github/master:refs/heads/master
```

Comment: I've already got that working. It does look like there isn't going to be any way to avoid using the filesystem on the 3rd host :(

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for, but probably the most useful for people looking at this question.

Comment: I went with a simpler setup: create a github repo, clone it locally, add heroku as remote, then just `git push heroku master`.

Answer (score 2):

[Codeship.io](http://codeship.io) does this as a service now, and automatically configures the appropriate git webhooks on public or private github repos.

There are a few other "continuous integration as a service" (CIAAS) options out there, but in general they get around the problem you're specifically presenting: web hooks need to hit a 3rd-party service, which in turn can trigger the heroku build process.

These CIAAS hosts act as the 3rd-party, and usually offer a free tier for public projects. You can also roll your own by deploying a web hook receiving server, which can both pull and push git repos.

Comment: Codeship is actually free for 5 private repos; up to 100 deploys a month. I'm probably going to give it a try.

Comment: Actually I'm not; they don't support Python 3.x. But still, very cool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can push directly from GitHub to another remote repo.

So if you have many apps to push, you may consider an organization using submodules, [like in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544579/git-github-heroku).

You would still have to download a repo to push it on the Heroku node, but at least you can control what to pull/push (and do some cleaning between each push).

Comment: I won't actually be the owner of the apps(I'm building a cloud based service) so I won't have control over how they are organised.

Answer (score 0):

About a year after my previous answer about [codeship.io](https://codeship.io), Heroku launched the beginnings of their Pipeline feature set, which includes proper Github integration.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

The whole pipeline flow is really powerful, allowing for temporary instances based on branches, multiple app deployments, staging->production promotion, etc. More information can be found on Heroku's [overview article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines).