# Problem with git push remote behind proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, proxy, github

To set the context, I am trying to use the [toto](https://github.com/cloudhead/toto) to set up my blog.
I did

`$ sudo gem install toto`

and the gems were installed properly.

```
Successfully installed rdiscount-1.6.8
Successfully installed toto-0.4.9
2 gems installed
```

After that, I tried

```
$ git clone git://github.com/cloudhead/dorothy.git myblog
```

but I get the following error

```
Cloning into myblog...
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
```

My git http proxy settings are correct

```
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:~/myblog$ git config --global http.proxy
http://proxy:port
```

My http_proxy settings are also correct

```
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:~$ echo $http_proxy
http://proxy:port/
```

So, I replaced git by http, as

```
$ git clone http://github.com/cloudhead/dorothy.git myblog
```

and it worked.

Now, when I do the following

```
$ cd myblog
$ heroku create myblog
```

it works till here and I get

```
Creating myblog...... done
Created http://myblog.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:myblog.git
Git remote heroku added
```

But it fails down here:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

and the following error comes up

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I didn't know what to do, so after Googling a bit I found that you can't push changes to github using http.
On digging in further, I found this link

[how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy](http://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy/)

which says that you can have your firewall administrator configure the proxy to also allow CONNECT for port 9418, which is the port used by git.

Once they have appropriately configured the proxy, you should then be able to use tools like netcat-openbsd or socat to connect through.

My problem is that I am a student and I can't get around this because I can't reach out to the administrator. I don't know what to do, as I am still stuck looking for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added the `heroku` remote using this URL `git@heroku.com:myblog.git`. This was probably configured by the `heroku create` command.

When you push to this remote, it is done via SSH. And this is exactly what the error message indicates: that you (or git) tried to ssh to heroku.com, but couldn't because of your firewall (probably) denied that. With your `git push heroku master` command, you are **not** pushing to Github, but to the git repository at Heroku. To push your stuff to Github, you need to `git push origin master` and use either ssh or http for the transport. The `git://` protocol itself does not support pushing changesets but is an unauthenticated re-only protocol.

Currently, Heroku seems to only allow the SSH transport for its git repos and there don't seem to be any direct hooks on Github (see [Push from github to heroku without downloading repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo)). This means to publish your apps on Heroku, you *need* to be able to push to heroku.com via SSH from your local host.

Answer (score 2):

You can also push to https://cloudhead@github.com/cloudhead/dorothy.git (note the username in the url).

Comment: I tried doing push to git push `https://github_username@github.com/app_name.git` but it returned me an error `error: The requested URL returned error: 500 while accessing https://github_username@github.com/app_name.git/info/refs`.

Comment: @Jatin: you seem to have forgotten the owner of the repo in the repo path. You need to have the cloudhead before that @ (as a username) and after the github.com (as the repository owner).

Answer (score 1):

When you push to this remote, it is done via SSH. The error you are getting is because the client could not connect via SSH, most likely because you are behind some type of firewall that is preventing the connection. I used to have this same problem when trying to push to Heroku from work.

My suggestion would be for you to develop locally and then go to some public hotspot to push the changes to Heroku (like a Starbucks).