# heroku with Smart HTTP Support

Tags: heroku, github

Does heroku support a Smart HTTP Support like [github](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean for deployments via `git push`? Then **no**—because HTTP is not the protocol you use when you push to Heroku.

Comment: I have a corporate proxy so I can't push via ssh due firewall blocks 22 port.

Comment: I see. I guess you're out of luck then, as this answer also indicates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4980977/473467