# Github straight to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku

I have a project on a private github repository (but this should work for public repositories too) and there are many contributors. The github repository has been designated as the master copy. This project is set up to deploy to my app on heroku.com.

I would like to get the git push to go straight from github to heroku without first having to host it on my workstation. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this isn't possible: [Push from github to heroku without downloading repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this directly, but this should at least get you looking in the right area: http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/b5cf75ea59401b71?fwc=1&pli=1) might be of interest as well.