# Deploying Github Repo to Heroku without downloading git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, repository

Is there a way to deploy a GitHub repository to Heroku without using git? I tried the link at https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push but it's not seeming to work, can anyone help with this issue? And I know it's possible, i'm just not entirely sure how.

Comment: What's wrong with just installing git?

Comment: I want to have it so people can develop the application on the web anywhere they are by just editing the git repository, and then I would just push the app to Heroku from there, without them having to install git.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you can't push from Github directly to Heroku: [Push from github to heroku without downloading repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo)

This has also been discussed here: [Github straight to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236916/github-straight-to-heroku)