# github to heroku...Alreay exsistent application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I want to push my rails application from github to heroku. I have deployed my application on github and i have its url. I dont know how to deploy on heroku an application which already exists on github .
Anyone who knows please reply.Thanks

Comment: check here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has an excellent [Guide on deploying Rails 3 applications to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

Answer (score 0):

You can now deploy, on Heroku, either the master branch or a feature branch from a github repo. This deployment can be done either manually or automatically (when something changes on the branch in the github repo). To make this happen, login in to Heroku, click on the app, and click the "Deploy" menu pick.  Scroll down and you will see "Automatic" and "Manual" deploy choices. You can select one or both of these. A continuous integration tool -- like GoCD, Jenkins, or others -- would provide another layer of control and management for you. But this deployment method using just Heroku works well for individuals, small teams, or simple use cases.