# Need clear steps to pull Git app into Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm a Git/Heroku newbie and am having trouble with the steps in Heroku's documentation - I can't figure out this one crucial step (even after looking at related posts in StackOverflow, most assumed a workflow already in place).

In local dev, "myapp" is correctly hooked up to Git repository "myapp". I can push and pull commits, also see them on the GitHub site in the "myapp" repository.

In Heroku, I've created the app, "put-myapp-here-dangit", and under the setting "GitHub Repo", I've entered "(myusername)/myapp".

Heroku Toolbelt and GitHub command line tools are installed locally. In Terminal, `git remote -v` shows both repositories:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:put-my-app-here-dangit.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:put-my-app-here-dangit.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/myusername/myapp.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myusername/myapp.git (push)
```

This is where I'm stuck, and none of the documentation makes clear how to get the "myapp" files from GitHub to Heroku. I'm scared to blindly keep trying commands because I know I can make an svn mess if I use the wrong one.

[Heroku "put-my-app-here-dangit"] --> **help???** <-- [Git "myapp"] --><-- [local "myapp"]

Can anyone outline the actual steps needed, including things I might not know (like if I need to open the Terminal IN my local "myapp" folder or where - Git or Heroku - I need to add my other account as a collaborator if necessary)? I'm about to rip my hair out.

Comment: What guide are you referring to?

Comment: I'm using [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git], "Deploying with Git". Things get unclear in the middle.

Comment: That link gets me nowhere.

Comment: `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git`, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried getting it from GitHub to Heroku, but from your local machine to heroku. Pull the latest version to your local machine from github (if you don't have it already), then follow these steps:

- `$ heroku login`
- locally cd into your app, `$ cd myapp`
- `$ git push heroku master`

Also notice you need to use postgresql on heroku, so your gemfile should look as follows:

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2' # or whichever db you are using
end
```

The steps outlined above are from herokus official section on [how to get started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

Are you using the same guide? If so, where exactly are you encountering problems in there?

Comment: this is the guide: I'm using [devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git], "Deploying with Git". I run into trouble at "You can also take an existing Git repo and add a remote using the git URL provided when you created your app." I added the remote, but can not pull the files - instructions seem to stop with adding the remote.

Comment: As [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo/3373611#3373611) indicates you can't directly push from github to heroku. Remember that heroku requires you to use git, but not necessarily github. In other words, you don't need a repo on github just to use heroku - you just need to use git locally inside your app (which you are). I would really just push to heroku locally following the steps I outlined. Treat your github repo as repo for collaboration and as cloud git, your local repo as development repo and heroku for production.

Comment: What @Charles said, there are services that push to Heroku for you, but it's just different shades, ie. you stil need a copy of your app on that service

Comment: `git push heroku master` is right. Whether it's pushing from local or Git, it is pushing the latest committed code. Thanks!!